# MediaCodec Crashes on call to start()

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, decoder

I am trying to stage MediaCodec to act as a decoder for an h264 stream.  I cannot even get the MediaCodec to pass its call to start() without crashing.

Below is the logs.  Basically my SurfaceView.Holder callback occurs when the surface is created and when it is changed.  On surfaceChanged I fire up a thread which tries to init a MediaCodec.

The _surface instance is from surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder.getSurface())

```
String key_mime = "video/avc";
int w = 480;
int h = 360;
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(key_mime, w, h);

mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2000000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);

try
{
decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(key_mime);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
return;
}

decoder.configure(mediaFormat, _surface, null, 0);
decoder.start();
```

Log:

```
05-05 13:18:14.645  22393-22393/ca.example.app D/StreamActivity﹕ surfaceCreated()
05-05 13:18:14.645  22393-22393/ca.example.app D/StreamActivity﹕ surfaceChanged(android.view.SurfaceView$4@2e73a220, 4, 1368, 765
05-05 13:18:14.655  22393-22586/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [] Now uninitialized
05-05 13:18:14.655  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/OMXClient﹕ Using client-side OMX mux.
05-05 13:18:14.685  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded
05-05 13:18:14.685  22393-22588/ca.example.app E/ACodec﹕ onConfigureComponent mime.c_str() = video/avc
05-05 13:18:14.685  22393-22588/ca.example.app E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
05-05 13:18:14.685  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] DRC Mode: Port Reconfig Mode
05-05 13:18:14.685  22393-22588/ca.example.app W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7fa30c03 = 2141391875
05-05 13:18:14.735  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ExtendedCodec﹕ Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
05-05 13:18:14.735  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] OMX_QCOM_FramePacking_OnlyOneCompleteFrame is setting
05-05 13:18:14.765  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded->Idle
05-05 13:18:14.795  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow setBufferCount : 22, minUndequeuedBuffers : 4
05-05 13:18:14.795  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Allocating 22 buffers from a native window of size 294912 on output port
05-05 13:18:14.805  22393-22588/ca.example.app E/ACodec﹕ dequeueBuffer failed: Invalid argument (22)
05-05 13:18:14.805  22393-22588/ca.example.app E/ACodec﹕ Failed to allocate buffers after transitioning to IDLE state (error 0xffffffea)
05-05 13:18:14.805  22393-22588/ca.example.app E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -22)
05-05 13:18:14.805  22393-22588/ca.example.app I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded
05-05 13:18:14.805  22393-22587/ca.example.app E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0xffffffea, actionCode 0, while in state 5
05-05 13:18:14.805  22393-22586/ca.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2272
    Process: ca.example.app, PID: 22393
    android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: start failed
            at android.media.MediaCodec.native_start(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaCodec.start(MediaCodec.java:612)
            at ca.example.app.StreamActivity$StreamingVideoThread.run(StreamActivity.java:975)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am testing mostly on a Samsung Galaxy S4 which is at Android 5.0.1.  I have a feeling this device does not support MediaCodec?

**UPDATE**

If I remove all the mediaFormat.setInteger calls then the media codec starts fine.  Since my h264 stream has SPS/PPS info every 'n' frames the media codec is also working happily.  Timing information is off, it is playing the video way to fast but that is a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your right that the Samsung S4 doesn't support media codec very well. It does work but its very pedantic and doesn't support recycling well.

Samsung S4 and S6 have given tremedous bother for me. The Samsung A5 works perfect like every other device like HTC, Sont, LG, Nexus etc.

For Samsung S4 you need to configure the following:

```
mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyMaxWidth, SelectedPalette.Value.Width);
mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyMaxHeight, SelectedPalette.Value.Height);
mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyMaxInputSize, SelectedPalette.Value.Width * SelectedPalette.Value.Height);
```

(This is Xamarin btw but the calls are the same in Java). Then you must try and catch all uses of the mediaCodec.doSomething().

If you have a high enough api level you should use the async decoder callbacks android 21+. And you should also use mediaCodec.Reset(); on any exception you should try your best to reset the decoder back to its original state as best as you can:

Comment: How the above configurations works for samsung s4? is there any documentations on samsung regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

The mediaFormat.setInteger calls you have used are only for encoders please refer [Android Developer's site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html)

Fast playing videos can be controlled by using presentationTimeUS. For example, for a video with 25fps the presentationTimeUS value should be incremented by  40000 for every frame i.e [(1/frame_rate)* 1000000] (the duration of one frame in microseconds)

```
decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex,0,buffer.length,presentationTimeUS,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked normally after removing the following option from a particular device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE)

```
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32768642)